# Android animation flip cover and ease up (open book animation)

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have few buttons/images there. on clicking I would like such animation :

(image opens like )book cover opens, and related activity/fragment opens with ease in animation and gets full screen.

Any thoughts ?

Something similar happening in cook app iOS,  Link of cook app : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cook/id687560846?mt=8

P.S : I have added animation, gif will run uninterrupted once completely loaded.

[image: animation]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement this animation using standard android animator with animating book as a set of multiple `ImageViews` - each for page representation: Cover, BackCover, FirstPage. And after animation is finished launch activity or display fragment.

Animate with:

- x and y scale, `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "scaleY", ...)`
- x and y transform, `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "x", ...)`
- y-rotation `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "rotationY", ...)`

See my example

(Sure, this sample requires some optimizations/fixes, but for better understanding would be enough):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView mPage1;
    private ImageView mCover;
    private ImageView mCoverFullScreen;

    private AnimatorSet mAnimIncrease;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCoverFullScreen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cover_full_screen);
        mPage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.page1);
        mCover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cover);
        mCover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAnimIncrease.start();
            }
        });

        mCoverFullScreen.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (mCover.getMeasuredHeight() <= 0 || mCoverFullScreen.getMeasuredHeight() <= 0) {
                    return;
                }
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                    mCoverFullScreen.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    mCoverFullScreen.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }

                initAnimator(1000);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initAnimator(long animationDuration) {

        mAnimIncrease = new AnimatorSet();
        TimeInterpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        float deltaX = mCover.getMeasuredWidth() / 2f;
        float deltaY = mCoverFullScreen.getY() - mCover.getY();
        float scale = mCoverFullScreen.getMeasuredHeight() / (float) mCover.getMeasuredHeight();
        float scaleMiddle = (scale + 1) / 2f;

        float xStart = mCover.getX();
        float xEnd = xStart + deltaX;
        float xMiddle = xStart + deltaX * interpolator.getInterpolation(0.5f);
        float xScaledEnd = xStart + deltaX * scale;

        float yStart = mCover.getY();
        float yEnd = yStart + deltaY;
        float yMiddle = yStart + deltaY * interpolator.getInterpolation(0.5f);

        AnimatorSet coverFrontSet = new AnimatorSet();
        coverFrontSet.setDuration(animationDuration / 2);
        coverFrontSet.playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "rotationY", 0f, -90f),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "pivotX", 0f),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "x", xStart, xMiddle),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "y", yStart, yMiddle),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "scaleY", 1, scaleMiddle),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "scaleX", 1, scaleMiddle)
        );
        coverFrontSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerStub() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationStart(animation);
                mCover.setImageResource(R.drawable.cover);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                mCover.setImageResource(R.drawable.cover_back);
            }
        });

        AnimatorSet coverBackSet = new AnimatorSet();
        coverBackSet.setDuration(animationDuration / 2);
        coverBackSet.playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "rotationY", -90f, -180f),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "pivotX", 0f),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "x", xMiddle, xEnd),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "y", yMiddle, yEnd),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "scaleY", scaleMiddle, scale),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCover, "scaleX", scaleMiddle, scale)
        );

        AnimatorSet coverSet = new AnimatorSet();
        coverSet.play(coverBackSet).after(coverFrontSet);

        AnimatorSet page1Set = new AnimatorSet();
        page1Set.setDuration(animationDuration);
        page1Set.playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mPage1, "scaleX", 1, scale),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mPage1, "scaleY", 1, scale),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mPage1, "x", xStart, xScaledEnd)
        );

        mAnimIncrease.play(coverSet).with(page1Set);
        mAnimIncrease.setInterpolator(interpolator);
    }
}
```

And Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/page1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/page1"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cover"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover_full_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Cover book animation example]

Comment: Thank you Alexander, quite a good way around, but I need this to be working on tablet, but opening cover goes outside screen(completely invisible) for few seconds, any way around for this?

Comment: @Haris It is how standard rotationY animation works. I can suggest you 2 solutions: 1. (Simpler) Divide your animation on two parts - [1](opening & increasing till half) and [2](just increasing). 2. Implement custom animation in order to apply custom rotationY animation. Unfortunately I have no idea how to deal with second solution :) . I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am trying to implement first solution

Comment: @Oleksandr Solution is working but how to apply close book animation ?

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani you should swap 3rd and 4th parameters of the animations and probably change the order of animations. Unfortunately, don't have time to provide extended answer.

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani, you are welcome. Upvote is a good way to say thanks :)

Comment: @Oleksandr Yeah sure I do.. Any Idea how do we achieve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587125/how-to-do-flipping-greeting-card-in-ios in Android ?

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani I would say with regular Android animations it's tricky and visualization not really nice. Did you check libraries for that? I've found some: https://github.com/eschao/android-PageFlip & https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/ but they both do curl animation instead of straight page you need. Maybe you can customize the behavior or find another library.

Comment: @Oleksandr I found that already but this needs to have lot of customization to achieve the same effect

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani then you can split the animations in the answer and try to archive the same effect with Android native animations applying it to both sides of the book. I guess, it wouldn't that pretty in the end...

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use the android.graphics.Movie class to display (and run) an animated gif.

You can find some help on the class here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html

But probably of more help is a working example here: http://androidosbeginning.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/gif-animation-in-android.html

Comment: Thank you
I do not want to make gif, I want activity transition animation.